# Proving a theorem for all real numbers using mathematical induction

Tags: induction

For the sake of this question, let us consider the De Moivre theorem. As of now, I am able to prove
$(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{n} = \cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)$
for all integers(positive and negative).

Using the fact that the theorem holds good for integers, if I try to prove the theorem for $\frac{a+b}{2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, will this prove the theorem for all real numbers?

Note: The intent of this question is NOT to prove the theorem for all real numbers, but to discuss whether proving a theorem for $\frac{a+b}{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers is a valid method to prove for all real numbers

Comment: Can you describe what you want to prove? You mean AM-GM inequality?

Comment: How would you prove de Moivre's theorem for $\pi$ or $e$?

Comment: There is a problem. $(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^{1/2}$ has TWO values. Every complex number, except for $0$, has two square roots.

Comment: @stevengregory and J.W.Tanner, my question was about using $\frac{a+b}{2}$ for proving a theorem for real numbers, be it de moivre or not. Probably De Moivre theorem has some complexities, but I just wanted to know whether the concept of using $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is valid.

Comment: The De Moivre theorem you quote does not hold in general when $n$ is not an integer. Raising complex numbers to non-integer powers is multi-valued unless we decide to interpret as giving _principal_ values -- and in the latter case a counterexample would be $\theta=-\pi$, $n=1/2$.

Comment: That wouldn't even prove it for all of the rational numbers as some rational numbers have odd denominators. The closest idea to what you're looking for may be the Herglotz Trick.

Comment: @NoLand'sMan: You have a _concrete example_ where the principle you propose does not work. How does that _not_ immediately lead to "this principle is not valid"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, De Moivre was just an example, my questionw as regarding proving any theorem for real numbers using induction.

Comment: Let me restate it then.  $(\cos x + i \sin x)^{\frac{a+b}{2}$ has two values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this were a valid proof technique, you could use it to prove that all real numbers are rational: clearly all integers are rational, and if $\frac pq$ and $\frac rs$ are rational then so is 
$$
\frac{\frac pq + \frac rs}2 = \frac{ps + rq}{2qs}.
$$
Therefore this is not a valid proof technique for proving something for all real numbers.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understood what you mean to say, are you implying that this proof would not account for irrational numbers?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan, indeed. (In fact it would not account for every rational either, such as $\frac13$. It only accounts for the so-called *dyadic rationals*.)

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

No it would not work as you suggested.

If you could prove the theorem for example for all rational numbers (more generally: any dense subset of the reals), then you could conclude that it holds for all real numbers by a continuity argument (the expressions occuring in the formula you gave as an example define continuous functions).

The problem you have is that expressions of the form $\frac{a+b}{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers do not form a dense subset of the reals, so you cannot conclude that the formular holds for all real numbers.

Edit: Maybe I was a bit unclear: Of course the conclusion from the rationals to the reals is only possible if we want to prove a formular which depends continuously on the variable over which we are inducing. If that's not the case (as for example in Mees de Vries' answer) then this does not work. But as the OP explicitly gave an example where we actually have a formula depending continuously on the variable we are inducing I thought that this was actually the point he was interested in.

Comment: This wouldn't be enough either. At best this would prove the claim for rational numbers. That is not the same as proving it for the reals. See Mees de Vries answer for an example.

Comment: The numbers you can get by starting from $\mathbb Z$ and _repeatedly_ taking averages _are_ dense in the reals.

Comment: @quarague: I wrote that if one can prove it for the rationals and the expression to be proved is continuous in the variable over which we "induce" then it holds for all reals. I cannot see how this can be wrong. Mees de Vries counterexample does not contain a "formular" to prove so it does not contradict to what I was saying.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I thought about the set $\frac{a+b}{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers as in the original question.